# Check if child data exists before deleting parent

Tags: php, html

I have news_Category and news table, here every news comes under one category,so before deleting new_category I want to display user a msg that child news exists in this category so u are not allowed to delete, If there are no child news than a confirm alert to user that "do u really want to delete".If he confirms the news category gets deleted.

**HTML STUFF**

```
<?php  echo "<a style='color:red;'' 
  href='delete.php?delete=$values[category_id]&
   img=$values[category_image]'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a>"; ?>



if ($_GET['msgError'])   {
echo "<script>alert('First Delete The News Than Category');</script>";
}
if ($_GET['msg'])   {
?>
<?php 
   }
   ?>
```

**DELETE.PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
 $id= $_GET['delete'];
 $img=$_GET['img'];
 $obj=new commands();
 $obj->delete_category($id,$img);
 }
```

**Delete Function**

```
   function delete_category($id,$img)
   {
       $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT category_id FROM nm_news where category_id='$id'");
       $stmt->execute();
       $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       if ($result) {
           header('Location: news_category.php?msgError=' . urlencode(base64_encode("First Delete The News Than Category")));
       } else {
           $sql = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM `nm_category` WHERE category_id=:id");
           $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
           $sql->execute();
           unlink("uploads/" . $img);
           header('Location: news_category.php?msg="confirm"');
           $this->con = null;
       }
   }
```

I am not able to make to logic here, how can I check whether the child news exists so i can display error msg and if there is no child news how to show confirm alert to allow delte

Comment: and what is blocking you exactly?

Comment: I am not able to make to logic here, how can I check whether the child news exists so i can display error msg and if there is no child news how to show confirm alert to allow delte

Comment: Your first SQL is still wrong. Don't follow cargo cult: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement

Answer (score 2):

You need to check to see if the result is empty.

Something like this:

```
function delete_category($id,$img)
   {
       $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT category_id FROM nm_news where category_id='$id'");
       $stmt->execute();
       $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       if (empty($result)) {
           header('Location: news_category.php?msgError=' . urlencode(base64_encode("First Delete The News Than Category")));
       } else {
           $sql = $this->con->prepare("DELETE FROM `nm_category` WHERE category_id=:id");
           $sql->bindParam(':id', $id);
           $sql->execute();
           unlink("uploads/" . $img);
           header('Location: news_category.php?msg="confirm"');
           $this->con = null;
       }
   }
```

**Edit due to extra details request**

On the front end you just need to display the GET msgError like this:

```
<?php isset($_GET['msgError']) ? echo url_decode(base64_decode($_GET['msgError'])) : '' ?>
```

Where you want to show the message text.

Comment: But I want the logic to display msg on front side, My PDO is working fine man !